# Avoid persian/arabic characters join within two tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, arabic, farsi

I have two same html code with diffrent result.
Because of the gulp compressing html files and removing extra break lines my codes looks like first block but I dont want my word join together.

```html
<p><span>آقای</span><span>اکبری</span></p>
<!-- Wrong: آقایاکبری -->

<p><span style="margin: 0 5px;">آقای</span><span style="margin: 0 5px;">اکبری</span></p>
<!-- Wrong: آقایـ ـاکبری -->

<p>
  <span>آقای</span>
  <span>اکبری</span>
</p>
<!-- Correct: آقای اکبری -->
```

Comment: They're not the same. The second one has white space between the `<span>` elements.

Comment: Your compression software is doing the wrong thing, in other words.

Comment: @Pointy Files are compressed with some gulp html compressor, is there any css solutions to avoid this behaivior ?

Comment: You can give the first span a `margin-right`

Comment: @Pointy I updated my question with margin, not work.

Comment: You're adding margin to both sides of each `<span>`. I would add `margin-right` or `margin-left` on one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Using an entity code will stop your compressor from removing whitespace as it isn't whitespace. `&nbsp` is a non-breaking space.

```html
<p><span>آقای</span>&nbsp;<span>اکبری</span></p>
```

Comment: Yes but that fixes the size of the space. Personally I would use margin, or, even better, not use a compressor that breaks the markup.